# SHBrowseForFolder network browsing performance issue

Tags: c++, windows, unc

One our customer complains on performance (and even hanging) when browsing network with shell "Browse for folders" dialog. They confirm that File/Open dialog(actually CFileDialog) works much faster:

> "is critical since the users needs to browse for model folders using
>   UNC paths and the current dialog  could make user to use the task
>   manager ... Just try browse for a UNC-paths in this dialog and compare
>   with browsing for a project file and you will see the
>   difference. The latter work  quick like Windows Explorer’s address
>   field, but the other uses some other method similar to Network
>   browsing in Windows explorer."

I haven't found any documentation on MSDN or Windows support regarding UNC paths perfomance neither for SHBrowseForFolder(), nor for MFC' CFileDialog, nor for WinAPI's GetOpenFileName().

And it's quite unsuitable to do testing on customer's site.

Any suggestions?

Comment: They've just reminded me that she has seen very slow performance of the Browse For Folders dialog on Unix, mainly because we seem to always start browsing at the root directory. (We're using MainWin to convert applications to Linux)

Comment: I've seen exactly the same thing, and it's caused by the network redirector having to search for systems on the network to populate the `network`. I was going to suggest using `IFileDialog` on Vista and newer, which supports typing in to the address bar, but if you're using MainWin, then I don't know if that would work in that situation. Mapped drives resolve pretty much instantly, though :(